# Sampling until first occurence

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume we have a bag of red and black marbles and we wish to sample from the bag without replacement until we find the first occurrence of a red marble (then we stop). If I am interested in finding the probability that no red marbles will be found amongst the first n marbles, does the probability change if I stop as soon as a red marble is found? In other words, is this problem equivalent to: the hypergeometric sampling of n marbles from the population, i.e. the probability that all n marbles are black in a sample of size n without replacement

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Which two probabilities are you comparing?  One of them is "the probability that there are no red ones among the first $n$ selections".  What is the second?

Comment: I edited it to make it clearer

Comment: Still not clear.  You start by describing a process..."keep selecting, without replacement, until you come to a red one".  That is not a probability.  I expect if you can state clearly what probability you are thinking of you'll be able to see the answer  to your question.

Comment: First scenario: I pick marbles until I see a red marble, then I stop. What is the probability for example that I don't stop within the first 10 marbles.

Comment: Second scenario: I pick 10 marbles from the bag, what is the probability that none of them are red. I believe they are both the same probability

Comment: Well, having phrased them like that...is it not clear that they are equivalent?  The first process stops if and only if there is a red one amongst the first $10$ so, yes,  the two events coincide.